# Need help disabling my touchpad

Tags: windows-8, touchpad

Right, I've searched the internet for days. I've tried getting new drivers and there is no button or gesture that manually disables my touchpad. If I go to my touchpad driver the "Disable" box is greyed out. I know that the i8042prt.sys controls both the touchpad and the keyboard, so if you can't give me any other method, can you tell me which files in i8042prt.sys control the touchpad so I can manually delete them? I don't care if the change is absolutely permanent as I have no use for my touchpad and if I ever need a mouse and don't have one I have a touchscreen.

Comment: I've actually looked at that question exactly, but none of the answers on that post worked for me, hence why I asked here just now.

Comment: You do understand that a .sys is a driver file which means if the author of the driver provides no way to configure the device through said drive files then you are likely simply out of luck.  More information on the specific touchpad in question is required to help.

Comment: I'm using a new HP Envy TouchSmart m6 Sleekbook, the driver used to say PS/2 Compatible Mouse, but now I've updated the driver and now it says Synaptics PS/2 Port Compatible TouchPad. I just want the touchpad to be disabled even if it means destroying it, tho obviously I'd prefer not to actually take a hammer to it.

Comment: The simplest way to disable the driver is to either delete the driver file itself by uninstalling the device and selecting that option or rolling back the driver itself.  Make sure you have the current revision of the driver otherwise features that exist only in the current revision, won't be presented to you.

Comment: I've uninstalled the driver but when it restarts, the default driver comes back. Now it says PS/2 Compatible Mouse again.

Comment: @DavidBrown - Which is what I thought you wanted?  The default PS/2 driver would disable the touchpad.

Comment: No, it won't. On the default PS/2 driver the "Disable" box is greyed out, just like in the picture on the other thread you linked.

Comment: The disable button in the duplicate question's screenshot isn't disabled I also didn't link to it.

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure it out and nobody has actually given me a good answer so... plz help :)